# Generating random string by TypoScript

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Is it possible to auto generate a mixed string of digits and letters by TypoScript, e.g. `12A54` or something similar?

Comment: Does any of the provided ansers work? Can you mark the question as resolved if so?

Answer (score 7):

I'd prefer a userFunc to a php include script. For example, you can pass parameters to a user function.

**Typoscript:**

```
includeLibs.generateInvoiceNo= fileadmin/scripts/generateInvoiceNo.php
temp.invoiceNo = USER
temp.invoiceNo {
  userFunc =user_generateInvoiceNo->main
}
```

**PHP:**
*fileadmin/scripts/generateInvoiceNo.php*

```
<?
class user_generateInvoiceNo {
    var $cObj;// The backReference to the mother cObj object set at call time
    /**
    * Call it from a USER cObject with 'userFunc = user_generateInvoiceNo->main'
    */
    function main($content,$conf){
        $length = 6;
        $chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        $number=substr(str_shuffle($chars),0,$length);
        return $number;
    }
}
?>
```

**Credits:**

- [This php script](http://codepad.org/5rHMHwnH)
- [TYPO3 Wizard on userFunc](http://www.typo3wizard.com/en/snippets/common-problems-and-solutions/simple-userfunc.html)

Answer (score 5):

As already mentioned, there is no such functionality in Typoscript and so the **preferred method** is to use some simle PHP function as suggested in other answers.

However, there is a **cheat** and that would be to use MySQL. Mind you, that it's a solution only if you absolutely cannot (for a reason that I really cannot think of) write a piece of custom PHP. Take it rather as an **academic answer** than a practical one.

```
temp.random = CONTENT
temp.random {
  table = tt_content
  select {
    pidInList = 1
    recursive = 99
    max = 1
    selectFields = SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 6) AS random_string
  }
  renderObj = TEXT
  renderObj {
    field = random_string
    case = upper
  }
}
```

**NOTES:**

1. `pidInList` must point to an existing page.
2. The MySQL command is really just an example as the string would never contain letters G-Z. I'm sure it's possible to come up with a better string generated by MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

Patching TYPO3 sources for such easy tasks is wrong idea. After the next source upgrade you'll lose your changes.

Instead it's better to include an easy PHP script where you can render what you need [check TSREF](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsref/4.7.0/view/1/12/)

Comment: Ok Markus - you have right. I need this for invoice number, but maybe the best solution will be to use id number of Formhandler element?

Comment: Well AFAIK in Poland invoices _should have_ sequential numbering: http://www.pit.pl/numeracja_faktur_8424.php so it can be a problem if you'll use formhandler for other purposes (kochany urząd skarbowy może się czepić) ;) If you are gonna create a proffesional system better go with custom extension and keep separate index for invoices numbers.